# Keep active state for link to a resource with fixed id using currentWhen

Tags: ember.js

Based on following router definition

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('songs', function() {
    this.resource('song', { path: ':song_id' });
  });
});
```

I have a main navigation link to a nested resource with a fixed id:

```
link-to 'First Song' 'song' 1 currentWhen='song'
```

The `songs` template renders also navigation links to the `song` resources and includes the `outlet` for the final `song` template.

My goal is to render the `song` template with song 1 by default after clicking the main navigation link but to keep this navigation link active for any other songs rendered in the outlet: [example in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zenehohudo/2/edit?html,js,output).

The `currentWhen` option on the link-to helper as shown above keeps the link only for resource 1 active but not for other `song` resources. When using the parent resource `songs` as `currentWhen` parameter it is never active.

Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding something?

I supposed that using a parent resource as the parameter for `currentWhen` would keep the link active for all nested resources, but this isn't the case.

I've also tried another solution where the main navigation link-to points to the `songs` route which uses `transitionTo('song', 1)` in the 'activate'-hook but this works only for the first time the link is clicked.

I'm using ember.js 1.7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the link to songs be as follows:

```
<li>{{link-to 'Songs' 'songs' currentWhen='song'}}</li>
```

Then, define a `SongsIndexRoute` which will redirect to the first song as follows:

```
App.SongsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function(model, transition){
    return this.transitionTo('song', 'first');
  }
});
```

Check it out [here](http://jsbin.com/puwonetura/1/edit?html,js,output)